# How to create user input parameters to increase product prices in a Products table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-input

I need to create a stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio to increase the prices in a table by certain percentages using input parameters. The procedure needs to have a user input parameter for CategoryID (@CategoryID), and when they input CategoryID 1, the UnitPrice in the Products table should increase by 10%(UnitPrice*1.1). If they input CategoryID 2 it increases by 15% and 7% for CategoryID4 etc. And for all other Categories the UnitPrice should remains the same. I'm using the popular Northwind sample database.

```
USE [Northwind];
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE usp_IncreasePrices_test2
(
@CategoryID int
)
RETURNS int
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @CategoryID int
SELECT @CategoryID = (dbo.OrderDetails[UnitPrice]*1.1)
```

This is what I have so far I know it's probably wrong though any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very strange logic, anyway you would do this something like this...

```
CREATE PROCEDURE usp_IncreasePrices_test2
    @CategoryID  INT  = NULL
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;
  Declare @PriceUp DECIMAL(5,2);

 SET @PriceUp =   CASE 
                     WHEN @CategoryID = 1 THEN 1.10
                     WHEN @CategoryID = 2 THEN 1.15
                     WHEN @CategoryID = 4 THEN 1.07
                     ELSE  1.00
                    END

  UPDATE dbo.Products
    SET UnitPrice = CAST( UnitPrice * @PriceUp AS DECIMAL(5,2))
  WHERE Categoryid = @CategoryID

END
```

Comment: Tip `BEGIN..END` doesn't do what most people think it does. They can be deleted with zero effect. The only things that identify the end of a stored proc are `GO` or the end of the script.

Comment: @CraigYoung I understand the use of `BEGIN...END` and never use it as a batch separator , It is only used to separate blocks of code. Also makes it look cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: I'm not questioning your understanding of `BEGIN..END` in stored procedures (as used here). Just trying to raise awareness of an unexpected surprise for those who don't know. If you interpret "easier to read" as in "_aesthetically pleasing_": I agree, it does look better. However, if you interpret as "_easier to understand **correctly**_": then this code is easily misinterpreted. It looks like `END` ends the proc. So someone might add a `SELECT` after `END` to check data in the table. Run _that_ script and be very unpleasantly surprised that every time you call the proc it also `SELECT`s.

Comment: It's "very strange logic" because it's a homework assignment.